# Como abrir uma imagem externa no Tkinter após a execução?

Tags: python, imagem, tkinter

Fala galera, beleza??

Gostaria de saber como adicionar uma imagem externa ao tkinter após a execução do código.

Algo nesse sentido:

[image: imagem de exemplo]

Testei essa função:

```
def get_path_image(label):
    path = filedialog.askopenfilename(
    initialdir = "/Downloads/",
    title = "Selecione a imagem",
    filetypes = (("Arquivos tif", "*.tif"), ("Todos os arquivos", "*.*")))
    
    image_original = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))

    new_image = image_original.resize((352, 302), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)

    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(new_image)

    label.configure(image=image, width=353, height=303)
```

Mas, sempre fica assim: (as bordas já são do código mesmo rsrsrs)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O path para imagem está correto? Seria a primeira coisa que eu checaria...

Comment: Está sim! Foi a primeira coisa que chequei quando começou a dar esse problema.

Quando seleciono a imagem não apresenta erro nenhum, porém não acontece mudança nenhuma na interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui solucionar uma parte do problema da seguinte forma:

```
label.configure(image=image, width=352, height=302)
label.image=image
```

Eu conversei com um professor e ele me disse que havia passado por uma situação parecida e que a solução que ele encontrou foi fazer uma redundância na parte de atribuir a imagem a label.

Comment: Amigo, se tens outro problema, abra uma nova pergunta e referencie essa aqui para pegar o contexto.

Answer (score 0):

`ImageTk.PhotoImage` não tem a função `resize()`. Você deve redimensionar a imagem antes de passar para `ImageTk.PhotoImage`.

Um exemplo:

```py
imagem_original = Image.open(path)
imagem_redimensionada = imagem_original.resize((352, 302), resample=Image.LANCZOS)
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagem_redimensionada)
```

Comment: Eu mudei após a postagem aqui e mesmo assim não funcionou